# How to setup browser-sync with Wordpress and xampp

Tags: php, wordpress, gulp, xampp, browser-sync

In my gulpfile.js I have the following code:

```
const themeName = "test"
const browsersync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Browsersync
function browserSyncServe(cb) {
  browsersync.init({
    proxy: `localhost/${themeName}/`,
    notify: {
      styles: {
        top: 'auto',
        bottom: '0',
      },
    },
  });
  cb();
}
function browserSyncReload(cb) {
  browsersync.reload();
  cb();
}

// Watch Task
function watchTask() {
  watch('*.html', browserSyncReload);
  watch('*.php', browserSyncReload);
  watch(
    ['src/scss/**/*.scss', 'src/**/*.js'],
    series(scssTask, jsTask, browserSyncReload)
  );
}

// Default Gulp Task
exports.default = series(
  browserSyncServe
);
```

It seems not so convinient to enter `themeName` for every single new project and match `themeName` with Wordpress theme folder name.

Is there any possibility to make it more automatic?
I'm trying to set up browser-sync together with Wordpress website on xampp.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert on Browsersync, but I am a WP and xampp user who got it to work perfectly with the following config:

```
browserSync( {
    proxy: "https://localhost/mysite/",
    https: {
        key: "W:/xampp/htdocs/mkcert/localhost/localhost.key",
        cert: "W:/xampp/htdocs/mkcert/localhost/localhost.crt"
    }
});
```

NB: I am using xampp and it's installed on W:/ drive. I am also using mkcert for SSL.

You can [learn more here](https://blogjunkie.net/2017/04/enable-https-localhost-browsersync/).